# How can I construct error messages Dynamically (using variables) when raising an exception in a Snowflake SQL Block?

Tags: sql, error-handling, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I call the stored procedure "SALES.ORDERS.ERROR_CHECK", which outputs one row either saying "Passed: Row counts match." or "Failed: Row counts do NOT match."

In the case where the output of the stored proc. is "Failed: Row counts do NOT match.", I want to raise an exception with the error message being the output of the stored proc. ("Failed: Row counts do NOT match.") and stop execution of any SQL that comes after the following script block:

```
CALL SALES.ORDERS.ERROR_CHECK($database_name, $table_name, $initial_count, $final_count, '=');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
    msg VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    msg := (SELECT ERROR_CHECK FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id()))); 
  IF (msg LIKE '%Failed%') THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION msg;
  END IF;
END; 
$$;  

--The below should NOT run if the script block returns "Failed: Row counts do NOT match.":
SELECT 'End of Script';
```

What I'm trying is not working, I keep getting the error "syntax error line 6 at position 8 unexpected 'LIKE'."

Please provide any answers in SQL and NOT Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `LIKE` in an `IF` in SQL scripting.
Something like this should do it though:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
    msg VARCHAR;
    res boolean;
    my_exception EXCEPTION (-20002, 'Raised MY_EXCEPTION.');
BEGIN
    msg := 'Here is a Failed error message';
    SELECT CONTAINS(:msg, 'es') INTO :res;
    LET should_raise_exception := :res;
    IF (should_raise_exception) THEN
        RAISE my_exception;
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

When I run it I get back:

[image]

Comment: So the issue is when I run this through prefect (similar to airflow) the error doesn't actually stop the flow. When that stored procedure returns an error I want the next lines of SQL to NOT run.

Comment: To achieve that you need to include all the SQL statements like `SELECT 'End of Script';` in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` block otherwise they will be executed since only that block will throw an exception. So in the `IF` block just add an `ELSE` and add all the other SQL statements.